# how to apply preprocessing methods on several columns at one time in sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

My question is I have so many columns in my pandas data frame and I am trying to apply the sklearn preprocessing using dataframe mapper from sklearn-pandas library such as

```
mapper= DataFrameMapper([
    ('gender',sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()),
    ('gradelevel',sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder()),
    ('subject',sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder()),
    ('districtid',sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder()),
    ('sbmRate',sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()),
    ('pRate',sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()),
    ('assn1',sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()),
    ('assn2',sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()),
    ('assn3',sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()),
    ('assn4',sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()),
    ('assn5',sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()),
    ('attd1',sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()),
    ('attd2',sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()),
    ('attd3',sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()),
    ('attd4',sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()),
    ('attd5',sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()),
    ('sbm1',sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()),
    ('sbm2',sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()),
    ('sbm3',sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()),
    ('sbm4',sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()),
    ('sbm5',sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler())
 ])
```

I am just wondering whether there is another more succinct way for me to preprocess many variables at one time without writing them out explicitly.

Another thing that I found a little bit annoying is when I transformed all the pandas data frame into arrays which sklearn can work with, they will lose the column name features, which makes the selection very difficult. Does anyone knows how to preserve the column names as the key when change the pandas data frames to np arrays?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I'd just create a new encoded column and pass these to scikit learn if you want nice column names, you could write a scaling function that took the columns and applied the appropriate encoder depending on type and generate the new column name by adding a prefix _encoded or similar

Comment: Hi @EdChum Thank you so much for the reply! But I still can't get through the prefix_encoded part. Would you please kindly post some codes about that? Thank you so much for your help! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer, LabelEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn_pandas import DataFrameMapper

encoders = ['gradelevel', 'subject', 'districtid']
scalars = ['sbmRate', 'pRate', 'assn1', 'assn2', 'assn3', 'assn4', 'assn5', 'attd1', 'attd2', 'attd3', 'attd4', 'attd5', 'sbm1', 'sbm2', 'sbm3', 'sbm4', 'sbm5']
mapper = DataFrameMapper(
    [('gender', LabelBinarizer())] +
    [(encoder, LabelEncoder()) for encoder in encoders] +
    [(scalar, StandardScaler()) for scalar in scalars]
)
```

If you're doing this a lot, you could even write your own function:

```
mapper = data_frame_mapper(binarizers=['gender'],
    encoders=['gradelevel', 'subject', 'districtid'],
    scalars=['sbmRate', 'pRate', 'assn1', 'assn2', 'assn3', 'assn4', 'assn5', 'attd1', 'attd2', 'attd3', 'attd4', 'attd5', 'sbm1', 'sbm2', 'sbm3', 'sbm4', 'sbm5'])
```

Comment: Hi @U2EF1  Thank you so much for the reply! But do you know how to keep the name of the column when I change them into np array? Thx so much!!

Comment: also I kind of can't understand what +\ for...I think it kind of a separator for two lines of codes. Why the comma can't work here? sorry i am really new to the Python world. Thx again!

Comment: @MYjx I don't know how to push your columns through. Numpy has structured arrays, but I'm not sure what sklearn would do with them. And you're right the \ just lets you continue the line, but it's unnecessary here inside parens.